# Click on Android button to open React Native component

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio

I would like to invocate a React Native component from Android. However, I am having issues when creating the intent and start the activity:

Settings.java

```
 public void goToReactNativeView() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Settings.this, MyReactActivity.class );
    startActivity(i);
  }
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.this, MyReactActivity.class );
               ^
    constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Settings cannot be converted to String)
    constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Settings cannot be converted to Context)
```

and the use of this is throwing error as well:

```
error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(Settings,Class<MyReactActivity>)
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyReactActivity.class );
               ^
    constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Settings cannot be converted to String)
    constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Settings cannot be converted to Context)
```

Edit based on suggestion provided by @Sarmad Ali:

When changing to sending `this` as parameter in goToReactNativeView and defining the parameter as Context in the body of goToReactNativeView function, I am getting the following error:

```
'goToReactNativeView(android.content.Context)' in 'java.com.awesomeproject.common.settings.Settings' cannot be applied to '(java.com.awesomeproject.common.settings.Settings)'

Required type: Context
Provided: Settings
```

Settings.java

```
  ...
  reactNativeBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> goToReactNativeView(this));
  ...
  public void goToReactNativeView(Context context) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyReactActivity.class );
    startActivity(i);
  }
```

How I pass the context of the current class (Settings) if it is not with the use of this or class.this? Is there any difference when the second argument is a class extending ReactActivity?

Thanks

Comment: Try this `public void goToReactNativeView() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReactActivity.class );
    startActivity(i);
  }`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Pass the context as a parameter to your goToReactNativeView method:

```
public void goToReactNativeView(Context context) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyReactActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Call this method from your Settings class, passing the appropriate context:

```
// Inside your Settings class, when you want to start the React Native activity:
goToReactNativeView(this);
```

If you are still encountering the issue. please provide more information regarding the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried this way but still getting error : 'goToReactNativeView(android.content.Context)' in 'java.com.awesomeproject.common.settings.Settings' cannot be applied to '(java.com.awesomeproject.common.settings.Settings)'

Required type: Context
Provided: Settings
Seems that is expected Context instead of the class. I am confused because `this` should work.